# Haproxy: Is there a way to queue incoming request?

Tags: queue, haproxy, rate-limiting

Is there a way in HA-Proxy to queue incoming request.
I am trying to throttle request based on certain rate limiting criteria, but my current implementation denies the request or blocks any new connection.
This is a crude implementation at this moment. 
Instead of denying the request I want to queue them till my backend recovers.

Also, is there a way in Haproxy to rate-limit or queue request based on IP.

Comment: Have you seen this post? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750518/difference-between-global-maxconn-and-server-maxconn-haproxy

Comment: Thanks for the link. Answers a lot of question.
However, do you know how to know or set per-proxy queue and per-server queue. I was a little confused there.

Comment: maxconn can be set on the server line to set the queue for that server, and also in a "defaults" or "frontend" to set the proxy's overall queue. For example, we set "maxconn 5000" in the "defaults" and "maxconn 20" on each server line.

Comment: I get it. But how do I increase my kernel queue (I am using centos as proxy host)

Comment: To correct what I said before, adding "maxconn" to a "server" creates a queue in the backend, not just for that server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between global maxconn and server maxconn haproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750518/difference-between-global-maxconn-and-server-maxconn-haproxy)